# Forcing browser not to cache via headers and file versioning seems not to work

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, browser-cache, cache-control

I have single page application that is frequently updated and I need a way to prevent browsers to cache my web app.

I have added

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

to my headers. I also use file versioning and update my file names according to the newest version.

But to my observations, google chrome always caches my application.

What may be the root cause here?

On a different platform, I have read that using no-cache , no-store and must-revalidate may cause conflicts and the browser may choose to use whichever it want, I have yet to find further proof of that statement. AFAIK the browser should use the most restrictive statement.

Here are my response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 312
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 11 Oct 2021 22:01:42 GMT
ETag: "61643c76-138"
Last-Modified: Monday, 11-Oct-2021 22:01:42 GMT
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Comment: You need to add your "observations". What are the response headers? What makes you think the application is being cached? Also, note that filename versioning and never-caching are two different solutions to the same problem. There's no point in using both on the same resource. See [this article](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/) for best practices.

Comment: Hi there, my observations are - whenever my web application is updated  - all of the assets needs to be re-indexed, Failing to do so results in returning a white page. Manually clearing caches solves the problem. I have also went ahead and added the response headers

Comment: The first step would be to remove the conflicting `Cache-Control` headers.  Something is setting a `max-age` of one year. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "re-indexed". Show a screenshot from Chrome Dev Tools or similar showing what is happening when you access the page.